# Can I use $interval in a service?

Tags: angularjs

I started out, as I suppose many beginners do, with a little code, added some, bit by bit, and found myself with  everything in one huge controller.

So, I split my functionality and had a bunch of smaller controllers.

Then I wanted them to communicate with each other & I discovered services.

Then I read that controllers should be lean & mean and I started to move lots of logic from controllers to services.

Now I find that some old code, which read
`$scope.internetConnectionRetryTimer = $interval($scope.attemptInternetConnection, RECONNECT_ATTEMPT_FREQUENCY);`

when moved into a service as
`this.internetConnectionRetryTimer = $interval(this.attemptInternetConnection, RECONNECT_ATTEMPT_FREQUENCY);`
doesn't seem to be running the timer; either that or it is not calling the function upon expiry.

So, can I actually use $interval in a service?

### Update

Global vars:

SERVER is a URL and var RECONNECT_ATTEMPT_FREQUENCY = 5 * 1000;  // 5 seconds

Here's the code:

```
   this.attemptInternetConnection = function()
   {
        $interval.cancel(this.internetConnectionRetryTimer);

        var params = '?action=test_connection&user=dummy';  

        $http.get(SERVER + params).  
            success(function() 
                {
                    $interval.cancel(this.internetConnectionRetryTimer); 
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('internetIsAvailable');
                })
               .error(function(status) 
               { 
                    this.internetConnectionRetryTimer = $interval(this.attemptInternetConnection, RECONNECT_ATTEMPT_FREQUENCY);  
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('internetIsUnavailable');
               });                         
   };// attemptInternetConnection()
```

Comment: do you need to clear the interval if you change pages or if the instance of the service is destoryed ?

Comment: Well, it should run forever, but, yes, I might want to stop the timer, in order to save bandwidth, depending on what the user is doing. Good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No problem with that.
Here's an example:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">{{Data.Test}}</div>

angular.module('myApp', []).
controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.Data = {Test: 'Test'};
    myService.ChangeTest($scope.Data);
}).
service('myService', function ($interval) {
    this.ChangeTest = function (data) {
        $interval(function () {
            if (data.Test == 'Test') data.Test = 'Changed Test';
            else data.Test = 'Test';
        },500);
    }
});
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzRma/).

Comment: I implemented it the same way. but I have an issue where the method in my service is calling an api. I am able to print the response in service but not in my controller. do you know how to do that?

Comment: I guess that you should have posted another question, with your own code, linking to this one.

Answer (score 1):

That should work fine. Though it depends how the method `attemptInternetConnection` has been written as the code is not posted. If you are referrencing any variables specific to the service inside `attemptInternetConnection`, it should be accessed by a referrence to the service object like the sample given below.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/1J0qzw044WRHSFGvZyOD?p=preview

```
app.service('intervalTest', function($interval) {
  var me = this;
  me.comments = [{
    total: 3,
    comment: 'some comment 1'
  }, {
    total: 10,
    comment: 'some other comment'
  }];
  this.getComments = function() {
    return me.comments;
  };
  $interval(function() {
    console.log('interval executed');
    me.comments[0].total++;
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: well, I am referencing two globals (shudder), which are used throughout the app - a URL of a server, and the duration of the timer.  I can't use `self`, but it should be ok to use globals, I guess?

Comment: Globals should be fine though not the best way of doing it. Can you please post sample logic of your `attemptInternetConnection`